# Filter based on object value

Tags: angularjs

I have a group of objects in an ngRepeat directive:

```
{ 'name': 'John', 'age': 14 }
```

I'd like to filter based on age. Something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="dude in dudes | age: > 3"></div>
```

Does Angular have a built in filter for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="dude in dudes" ng-if="dude.age > 3"></div>
```

Or

```
<div ng-repeat="dude in dudes | filter:isGreaterThanThree"></div> 

$scope.filter:isGreaterThanThree= function(dude) {
    return dude.age > 3;
};
```